# Unable to access local apache2 server from my mobile on the same LAN

Tags: configuration, server, localhost, apache2

So i tried accessing my local server with the IP of the machine from my android phone which is on the same LAN and the failed to connect to the server. How do i configure apache for this to work? I'm running apache 2.4 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS.